# thymeleaf error : org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**what is expected**

after data binding, web page should reflect the data

**details**

> Controller code

```
@Controller
@Configuration
@Component
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Credentials c;

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new RequestData());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")

    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute RequestData greeting) {
        if (c.getUserName().equals(greeting.getId()) && c.getPassword().equals(greeting.getContent()))
        {
        return "result";
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

**RequestData.java**

```
public class RequestData {

    private String id;
    private String content;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

**Credentials.java**

```
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Credentials {

    public String userName;
    public String password;

     @Autowired
     private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public String getUserName() {

         return env.getProperty("spring.username");

            }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Autowired
    public String getPassword() {
         return env.getProperty("spring.password");

            }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

**result.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
    <p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
    <a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

able to compile, package the codebase and build the jar. however, when i run the jar file , getting following error :

```
2018-10-31 15:36:34.259 ERROR 8220 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[disp
atcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context
 with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is or
g.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringE
L expression: "greeting.id" (template: "result" - line 9, col 8)] with root caus
e

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property o
r field 'id' cannot be found on null
```

I am not sure where the issue is, thymeleaf doc says that , model attributes can be accessed with ${attributeName} and i am also using is the same, but then why it says "id cannot be found"

please suggest

Comment: Are you sure greetingForm method gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Spring mvc doc, I quote-

> What happens when a model attribute name is not explicitly specified?
>   In such cases a default name is assigned to the model attribute based
>   on its type. For example if the method returns an object of type
>   Account, the default name used is "account". You can change that
>   through the value of the @ModelAttribute annotation. If adding
>   attributes directly to the Model, use the appropriate overloaded
>   addAttribute(..) method - i.e., with or without an attribute name.

In your case,

```
@PostMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute("greeting) RequestData greeting) {
..
}
```